# Left-greedy vs right-greedy column assignment when reading text files in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Say we have a **log** file that includes lines like the following:

```
Mar-13-19:04:13 [error] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
```

This is **not** a CSV file. However, if I assume:

- `sep=' '`
- 3 columns

one could theoretically load this file into a dataframe in **at least** in two ways:

#### Left-Greedy

- Columns 1 and 2 are assigned to `sep=' '`-splits, and Column 3 is assigned to whatever text remains at the end of each line
- This would result in:

  - Col1 = `Mar-13-19:04:13`
  - Col2 = `[error]`
  - Col3 = `File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico`

#### Right-greedy

- Columns 2 and 3 are assigned to `sep=' '`-splits, and Column 1 is assigned to whatever text remains at the beginning of each line.
- This would result in:

  - Col1 = `Mar-13-19:04:13 [error] File does not`
  - Col2 = `exist:`
  - Col3 = `/var/www/favicon.ico`

---

With this, my questions are:

- How can I load this file in Pandas using the **left-greedy** pattern?
- If I specify `error_bad_lines=False` in `read_csv`, does Pandas follow a **left-greedy** pattern? a **right-greedy** pattern? or none of the above?

Comment: It would be easier if you included how that example line would look like in a dataframe. Your explanation might not be clear for everyone, but showing it as dataframe explains it visually.

Comment: I just updated the OP to show exactly how they would work in this example. Thanks @Erfan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read in the full log file as a dataframe with 1 column. Then use `str.split` with `expand=True` which expands each list to it's own column:

```
txt = StringIO('''Mar-13-19:04:13 [error] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
Mar-13-19:04:13 [error] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
Mar-13-19:04:13 [error] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
Mar-13-19:04:13 [error] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
Mar-13-19:04:13 [error] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
''')

left_greedy = True

# read in text file as one big dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(txt)

if left_greedy:
    df = df[0].str.split(pat=' ', n=2, expand=True)
else:
    df = df[0].str.rsplit(pat=' ', n=2, expand=True)

# assign correct column names
df.columns = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']
```

**Output `left_greedy=True`**

```
              Col1     Col2                                         Col3
0  Mar-13-19:04:13  [error]  File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico\n
1  Mar-13-19:04:13  [error]  File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico\n
2  Mar-13-19:04:13  [error]  File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico\n
3  Mar-13-19:04:13  [error]  File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico\n
4  Mar-13-19:04:13  [error]  File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico\n
```

**Output `left_greedy=False`**

```
                                    Col1    Col2                    Col3
0  Mar-13-19:04:13 [error] File does not  exist:  /var/www/favicon.ico\n
1  Mar-13-19:04:13 [error] File does not  exist:  /var/www/favicon.ico\n
2  Mar-13-19:04:13 [error] File does not  exist:  /var/www/favicon.ico\n
3  Mar-13-19:04:13 [error] File does not  exist:  /var/www/favicon.ico\n
4  Mar-13-19:04:13 [error] File does not  exist:  /var/www/favicon.ico\n
```

---

#### Back up method working for example line:

You can use the vanilla `split` method to arrange this by splitting from left or right. Then the pandas `DataFrame` constructor to define your dataframe:

```
txt = "Mar-13-19:04:13 [error] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico"

left_greedy = True

if left_greedy:
    txt = txt.split(' ', 2)
else:
    txt = txt.rsplit(' ', 2)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack(txt), columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
```

**Output**

```
              Col1     Col2                                       Col3
0  Mar-13-19:04:13  [error]  File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
```

---

If we set `left_greedy = False` we get:

```
                                    Col1    Col2                  Col3
0  Mar-13-19:04:13 [error] File does not  exist:  /var/www/favicon.ico
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, but this would only do it for a single line right? How would you do this for a text file with multiple lines?

Comment: Edited my method which works for my example text file @AmelioVazquez-Reina

Answer (score 1):

By default, pandas returns dataframe similar to right-greedy pattern with rest of the text assigned to index.

```
from io import StringIO
data = """Mar-13-19:04:13 [error] client File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico"""
pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep = ' ', names = ['a','b','c'])


                                                a   b       c
Mar-13-19:04:13 [error] client  File    does    not exist:  /var/www/favicon.ico
```

One way is to read the data in one column and extract desired values using regex,

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), names = ['data'])
df['data'].str.extract('(?P<a>.*)\s\[(?P<b>.*)\]\s(?P<c>.*)')
```

You get

```
    a               b       c
0   Mar-13-19:04:13 error   client File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
```